# Apache Buildr issue with ant task / Hash.from_java_properties

Tags: java, ruby, buildr

I have a buildr script that first loads a java properties file, then creates an ant task.  I'm getting an abort error: Buildr aborted! org/apache/tools/ant/DefaultLogger when running buildr.

Here's the (simplified) buildfile:

```
CONFIG = Hash.from_java_properties("a=1")

define "my_project", :version => "1.0" do

  ant("ant_test") do |ant_project|
    # do something
  end

end
```

I'm using Buildr 1.3.5 on OS X 10.6 with Ruby 1.8.7

stack trace:

```
** Invoke my_project (first_time)
** Execute my_project
Defining task my_project:shell:jirb
Defining task my_project:shell:clj
Defining task my_project:shell:bsh
** Invoke /Users/jsbowers/.m2/repository/org/apache/ant/ant/1.7.1/ant-1.7.1.jar (first_time, not_needed)
** Invoke /Users/jsbowers/.m2/repository/org/apache/ant/ant-launcher/1.7.1/ant-launcher-1.7.1.jar (first_time, not_needed)
** Invoke /Users/jsbowers/.m2/repository/org/apache/ant/ant-trax/1.7.1/ant-trax-1.7.1.jar (first_time, not_needed)
** Invoke /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/buildr-1.3.5/lib/buildr/java (first_time, not_needed)
Buildr aborted!
org/apache/tools/ant/DefaultLogger
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/Antwrap-0.7.0/lib/rjb_modules.rb:16:in `import'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/Antwrap-0.7.0/lib/rjb_modules.rb:16
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/Antwrap-0.7.0/lib/ant_project.rb:86:in `initialize'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/buildr-1.3.5/lib/buildr/java/ant.rb:74:in `new'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/buildr-1.3.5/lib/buildr/java/ant.rb:74:in `ant'
/Users/jsbowers/tmp/buildr_test/buildfile:9
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/buildr-1.3.5/lib/buildr/core/project.rb:225:in `instance_exec'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/buildr-1.3.5/lib/buildr/core/project.rb:225:in `define'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:636:in `call'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:636:in `execute'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:631:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:631:in `execute'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/buildr-1.3.5/lib/buildr/core/project.rb:625:in `execute'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/buildr-1.3.5/lib/buildr/core/application.rb:146:in `switch_to_namespace'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/buildr-1.3.5/lib/buildr/core/project.rb:624:in `execute'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/buildr-1.3.5/lib/buildr/core/application.rb:630:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/buildr-1.3.5/lib/buildr/core/application.rb:616:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/buildr-1.3.5/lib/buildr/core/application.rb:611:in `invoke'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/buildr-1.3.5/lib/buildr/core/util.rb:204:in `__send__'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/buildr-1.3.5/lib/buildr/core/util.rb:204:in `to_proc'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/buildr-1.3.5/lib/buildr/core/project.rb:281:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/buildr-1.3.5/lib/buildr/core/project.rb:281:in `projects'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/buildr-1.3.5/lib/buildr/core/project.rb:863:in `projects'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/buildr-1.3.5/lib/buildr/core/application.rb:400:in `raw_load_buildfile'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/buildr-1.3.5/lib/buildr/core/application.rb:218:in `load_buildfile'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/buildr-1.3.5/lib/buildr/core/application.rb:496:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/buildr-1.3.5/lib/buildr/core/application.rb:213:in `load_buildfile'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/buildr-1.3.5/lib/buildr/core/application.rb:137:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/buildr-1.3.5/lib/buildr/core/application.rb:496:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/buildr-1.3.5/lib/buildr/core/application.rb:135:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/buildr-1.3.5/bin/buildr:19
/usr/bin/buildr:19:in `load'
/usr/bin/buildr:19
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As answered on the Buildr mailing list, you need to add `Java.load` before your call to `Hash.from_java_properties` so RJB* is correctly initialized.

This is normally done automatically after the `buildfile` is loaded but since you're using Java objects during the loading phase, you need to tell Buildr explicitly.

(*) RJB = Ruby-Java Bridge

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a classpath problem, but I can't really say for sure with the information you have given.  Try running `buildr --trace` and posting the full results.

Just an aside, but questions of this sort are most easily asked and answered on the Buildr Users mailing-list.

Comment: added the trace and also posted over on the list.  Thanks for the tip.